# creating a pivot table from an SQL view, but view is not available in data connection wizard

Tags: sql, view, pivot

I'm trying to create an Excel pivot table from a Microsoft SQL view, however, my view is not showing up in the data connection wizard window.  Is there some setting that I'm missing that would allow me to see views, also?  Security privileges shouldn't be an issue, as I'm working at dbo priv level.

Answer (score 0):

never mind - i figured it out:  while the list appears to be a straight alpha sort, it actually lists all views, and then all tables.